# Generic function in a separate source file is unresolved

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, generics

I have attrs.xml that defines maxValue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="Gauge">
        <attr name="maxValue" format="float" />
    </declare-styleable>
    ...
```

and a getAttr fun in getAttr.kt:

```
inline fun <T: Any> getAttr(typedArray: TypedArray, index: Int, default: T): T {
    return when (T::class) {
        Float::class -> typedArray.getFloat(index, default as? Float ?: 0f) as T
        Int::class -> typedArray.getInt(index, default as? Int ?: 0) as T
        String::class -> typedArray.getString(index)?.let { it as T } ?: default
        Color::class -> typedArray.getColor(index, default as Int) as T
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported attribute type: ${T::class.java.simpleName}")
    }
}
```

When i try and use getAttr in Gauge.kt, it is undefined:

```
class Gauge(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : ViewGroup(context, attrs) {
    var maxValue: Float = 100f

    init {
        val sa = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Gauge, 0, 0)
        try {
            if (sa.hasValue(R.styleable.Gauge_maxValue)) {
                maxValue = getAttr(sa, R.styleable.Gauge_maxValue, maxValue) // getAttr is red, undefined
            }
        ...
```

Hovering over the red getAtttr shows

> TypedArrayUtils.getAttr can only be called from within the same
> library group prefix referenced groupid=androidx.core with prefix
> androidx from groupid=Gauges

Gauge.kt and getAttr.kt are in the same folder.

Importing getAttr with the fully-qualified name doesn't help.

Renaming getAttr everywhere doesn't change anything.

I've flushed caches, rebuilt, etc., all to no avail.

Could someone help me out please? Thanks.